# cells().paste VS cells.pastespecial?

Tags: excel, vba

How come below code works:

```
.Range("D4:F4").copy
.cells(1,1).PasteSpecial
```

While below doesn't work:

```
.Range("D4:F4").copy
.cells(1,1).Paste
```

I realize that the correct syntax is

```
.Range("D4:F4").copy Destination:=
```

Comment: what is the difference between the 2? They both look the same to me?

Comment: Fixed the mistake as soon as I saw it. Thanks!

Comment: I have rolledback the edit as your edit merged with my edit (system glitch?) I had just added the tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is very simple `.Paste` is not a property of the `Cells` object but of the `Worksheet` Object

If you type `.` after the `Cells`, Intellisense will confirm that fact :)

There are various ways to copy data across.

If you want to only copy values across and not the formatting then this is the best way

```
rng1.Value = rng2.Value
```

If you want to carry the formatting then either you can use

```
Rng1.copy Rng2
```

or

```
Rng1.Copy
rng2.pastespecial
```

Comment: While `PasteSpecial` is a property of a cell ? Is `*Source*.Copy *Destination*` the commonly used Copy/Paste method ?

Comment: No not necessarily. I can also use `Range("a1").value = Range("A2").value`

Comment: I have deleted my comment and updated it in my answer

Comment: How can I find out what properties `Cells` has ? [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196273.aspx) doesn't seem to list them.

Comment: If you type `.` after the Cells, intellisense can show you that or you can see [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197454.aspx)

Comment: Not sure if this is obvious, but it just clicked for me. `.Paste` being a property of sheets means that `.Paste(cells(1,1))` works.

Comment: Yes it will because the syntax is `sheet.paste(destination)` Like I said `.paste` is a property of the sheet and not the cells object :)